# How to refer to no named block in Magento 2

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, custom-block

I have block:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">title</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-title</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-title</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I want to overwrite "header" argument without changing this block. I tried:

```
<referenceBlock name="name">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">my value</argument>
        </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

but it is not working. When I added name="name" to original block, it worked. So how can I refer to original block without editing it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you need a `name` attribute to use a `referenceBlock` or `referenceContainer`.